# What is the best system requirements check tool?

Tags: hardware, configuration-management

At our small company we provide software to our clients that has specific requirements.  Most of our clients are very limited in their technology skills.  Quite often, when one of our users has a problem with our software, it is a result of their device not meeting the minimum system requirements.  However, it takes way to long to figure that out, and **I was hoping to find a tool that is easy for our clients to use that could check their device against the minimum requirements and report it back to us**.  What would be the best tool for that?

Something like this, but for hardware requirements: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/minimum-system-requirements/

Something like this, but where I can set custom minimum requirements: https://www.systemrequirementslab.com/cyri

Comment: I think this question misses the OS. And use tags [hardware] [configuration-management]; PM is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I move that all questions lacking OS requirements and price should be considered asking for FOSS solutions on Linux. That's what you want, right Jonathan?  While on it: What features should the software have? From what you wrote, a spreadsheat should do: you ask the customers, fill in your template, and you have the requirements.